# robust rank aggregation method in R

Tags: r

I'm currently on a placement of a biomedical science degree, attempting to conduct  a  meta analysis of  microRNA gene expression data. I have been asked by my  lecturer to  complete this using the robust rank aggregation method.

I have installed the relevant package into R ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RobustRankAggreg/index.html)  and have all of the data ( fold change gene expression and p value for each microRNA)  that I need from the articles, I'm just not sure what format the data needs to be in ( ie. whether I input the data into R  as one collective csv  file etc)  and then how I would go about performing the analysis.
Apologies in advance if this is simple, have only just  started using R and as such I don't really know what I'm doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks, Ben.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 0):

You should first read the package vignette/[manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RobustRankAggreg/RobustRankAggreg.pdf) to have some examples and at least get familiar with the most used ways to [import](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html) data into R. Then maybe you can give a more hands on example.